# Working with tiledata of different sizes

Tags: 2d, tiles, tilemap, tools

I recently bought an asset for my game, basically a tilesheet, with seperate pngs as well, but where as previously I've created tilemaps out of identically sized tiles these are all in varying sizes but scaled to fit in with say 128 x 128 tiles or 256 x 256 tiles.

so one of the main blocks might be 128 x 128 but some other elements of them may be slightly oddly sized such as  173 x 214, this obviously wont tile well as it is, so I was wondering how I should approach this? do i need a tile editor that can support layers with different dimensioned tiles? or do i need to find some way of chopping, padding and aligning these images into the same 128x128 tiles?

thanks

Comment: It's totally subjective: What do you *want* to do with them? Are they large sprites of houses you could split up and then use as regular tiles, or are they animation frames of large monsters you want to use as-is? The [*Tiled* editor](http://www.mapeditor.org/) (which is the first Google result for "tile map editor") certainly [supports tile layers](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-tiled-map-editor-a-great-platform-agnostic-tool-for-making-level-maps--gamedev-2838).

Comment: sorry I wasnt very specific. its basically a set of tiles for constructing a castle, but they are all in pngs of varying sizes, even if they are grouped into the 128x128 category some will be bigger / smaller, so i guess i need to get these all into correctly aligned tiles with any that are larger than 128x128 chopped in a way that i can piece it back together in a tile editor. yeah im using tiled, but you cant change the tile size on a per layer basis

Comment: @Stowelly, referencing this meta post:  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1082/is-it-fine-to-ask-what-are-tools-that-could-solve-your-problem/1083#1083  , perhaps you could revise your question to focus on accomplishing your requirements.  Your question is somewhat well-defined already, perhaps you could elaborate about your "per-layer" requirement.  There are lots of tile sprite sheet editors out there, but picking the right one is based on your information.  Add more of it.

Comment: thanks for the input, have refactored my question based on the research i have done since posting it!

Comment: Maybe you can post few examples of the problematic "tiles" in question.

Comment: http://2.s3.envato.com/files/67100554/tileableCastlePlatformGameAssets.jpg if you see the image at the bottom. the square made of bricks is 128 x 128 but some of the other bits, like the doors and the grass are differing in dimensions, i would like to be able to use these in a tilemap so they would have to be sliced up i assume

Comment: Im starting to wonder if I am approaching this wrong, maybe i just need some kind of editor that you can place sprites in rather than trying to split it all up into tiles....